# Building Caffe cpp_classification example in external context

Tags: c++11, gcc, protocol-buffers, caffe

I have already configured and built Caffe from the ground up in CPU_ONLY and GPU_ONLY modes (with the respective samples and tools); and fairly satisfied with the out-of-the-box results.

However, I am starting my own project derived from the cpp_classification example, and having difficulties in building it independent of the overall Caffe build system.  As such, I have gone back to the cpp_classification example and have been working to build that as a standalone (just to ensure that I am not leaving anything out) and encountering similar errors.

I sharing the contents of my build-errors output and the CMakeLists.txt with you in the hopes that someone else who has successfully hoisted the cpp_classification example can provide guidance.

I have narrowed down the build-errors I am getting to the following:

```
Scanning dependencies of target cpp_classification
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable cpp_classification
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `Classifier::Classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:62: undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Net(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Phase, int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, caffe::Net<float> const*)'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:63: undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `Classifier::SetMean(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:124: undefined reference to `caffe::BlobProto::BlobProto()'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:129: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::FromProto(caffe::BlobProto const&, bool)'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:135: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::mutable_cpu_data()'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:124: undefined reference to `caffe::BlobProto::~BlobProto()'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:124: undefined reference to `caffe::BlobProto::~BlobProto()'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `Classifier::Predict(cv::Mat const&)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:156: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::Reshape(int, int, int, int)'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:158: undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Reshape()'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:165: undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Forward(float*)'
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:169: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::cpu_data() const'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `Classifier::WrapInputLayer(std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >*)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:184: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::mutable_cpu_data()'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `Classifier::Preprocess(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >*)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:227: undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::cpu_data() const'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `caffe::Caffe::set_mode(caffe::Caffe::Brew)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/distribute/include/caffe/common.hpp:148: undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::Get()'
CMakeFiles/cpp_classification.dir/classification.cpp.o: In function `caffe::ReadProtoFromBinaryFileOrDie(char const*, google::protobuf::Message*)':
/home/rudycazabon/caffe/distribute/include/caffe/util/io.hpp:78: undefined reference to `caffe::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(char const*, google::protobuf::Message*)'
collect2
```

My corresponding CMakeList.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(cpp_classification)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(CAFFE_HOME ~/caffe/distribute)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
find_package(glog REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES classification.cpp)

include_directories(${CAFFE_HOME}/include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories(${CAFFE_HOME}/lib ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(cpp_classification
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        ${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cpp_classification
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLOG_LIBRARY}
        ${CAFFE_LIBRARY}
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARY})
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0")`

It tells gcc to use the old ABI for `<string>`.